# Link to base source code in GIT (C#)

Tags: c#, git, version-control, dependencies

I am developing a project which has to rely on base code in a separate projects (all in GIT), so that this base code can be used in other projects as well.

The solution I'm using now is to include the base code projects in my specific project. But we all know what will happen when someone finds a bug in the base code right? They will make changes to the local copy only.

Therefore, I want the base code to be in GIT and have the specific project depend on this. How can this be done?

I am using C# / Visual Studio 2013 and GIT. I have seen other customers using their own development environment which takes care of the synchronization. But I was wondering if there was something already made without developing my own environment? I have uploaded a small drawing of what I want to achieve

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aGmxa9a.png]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is already invented and it is called [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).